# Star Wars-inspired online 'game' focused on the Sith

Tags: star-wars, sith

I'm looking for the name of an unofficial website where you could role play (best way I can put it) as a Sith - while I'm not sure if the website outwardly labelled them Sith, or if there was ever any direct mention of Star Wars, at the very least the whole aesthetic and history of the Sith was the subject of this site. You could create a character, perhaps join a family, write a biography, you could study and take tests on various subjects about a lot of different things related to the Star Wars Universe. I believe you could 'quest' to make your own lightsaber, improve your ability flying space ships, things like this.

The website looked competently made with a lot of nice visuals but I'm quite sure most of the user's involvement was text based, or clicking from multiple choices presented.

I don't even remember exact timelines of when I would've visited this site. I want to say at least 10 years ago, potentially 10-15 years ago, maybe even older (the website seemed 'established' when I found it all that time ago.

I know it's not really a lot to go on but this is something that has been gnawing at me and I cannot seem to recall anything about the site's name, and all my searches get blitzed as the official Star Wars universe is so huge that all I get are official Star Wars search result suggestions.

Comment: Can you remember if the website was forum based? There was a set of forums for online RPGing about 15 years ago set in the Star Wars universe. I re-acquired the link to them awhile ago, but I now cannot find it to link back to them